# Starting Activity in android

Tags: android

I want to make an app which has two activities the first activity has a button to start the second activity. How do i create this this is my code which i want to execute for second activity.

```
public class Numbers extends Activity {
public static MediaPlayer mp = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_numbers);
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
private int[] mImages = new int[]  {R.drawable.no1,R.drawable.no2,R.drawable.no3,R.drawable.no4,R.drawable.no5,R.drawable.no6,R.drawable.no7,R.drawable.no8,R.drawable.no9,};
private int[] mAudio= new int[]{R.raw.one,R.raw.two,R.raw.three,R.raw.four,R.raw.five,R.raw.six,R.raw.seven,R.raw.eight,R.raw.nine,};
@Override
public int getCount() {
return mImages.length;
}
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
return view == ((ImageView) object);
       }
     @Override
     public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
     Context context = Numbers.this;
     ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
     int padding =context.getResources().  
     getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.activity_vertical_margin);
     imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
     imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
     imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
     ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);

if (mp != null) {mp.reset();
mp.release();
}
mp = MediaPlayer.create(Numbers.this,mAudio[position]);
mp.start();
return imageView;
            }

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
}
}
}
```

do i need to create two different layout activity in xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
    Button bt= (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourbtn_id);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, Numbers.class);
                startActivity(intent);
        }           
    });
```

Or

**XML:**

```
 <Button 
    android:id="@+id/yourbtn_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="BtnClick"
    android:text="Button" />
```

**JAVA:**

```
    public void BtnClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, Numbers.class);
                startActivity(intent);
    }
```

don't forget to add in manifest.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Numbers"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your 1st class:

```
public void goTo(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(this, 2ndClassActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and in xml design add this line to the button:

```
android:onClick="goTo"
```

Comment: i have added this code properly but my first activity is not getting launched after making changes in mainfest.xml... it just launch & displaying black window nothin else :(

Answer (score 0):

In your first Activity, when button is pressed, do:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Numbers.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

You need to have Numbers Activity in AndroidManifest too:

```
<activity android:name=".Numbers"></activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the onClick method or Listener of the button.

```
startActivity((new Intent(this, Numbers.class)));
```

Comment: Note :`this` does not refer to activity context in annonymous inner class. should be `ActivityName.this`

Comment: If a Listener is used, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

   Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext() , NextActivity.class);

   startActivity(intent);

   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you have to create two layouts..one for first activity which have your button and second layout for another activity in which you execute

refer to : http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/android-sending-data-from-one-activity-to-another/